# What is this metal part that came with the MSI z790 Carbon Wifi?

Tags: motherboard, intel

[image]

It has a slot at the end that looks like something may be inserted, but it does not look to be a micro SD card reader as it has no way to plug into a PC. It came in an individual shielded bag in the motherboard's box.

The motherboard's manual can be found here: https://download.msi.com/archive/mnu_exe/mb/MPGZ790CARBONWIFI.pdf
It makes no mention of this part or it's use. I thought it might be used for intrusion alarms, but this doesn't seem to even work for that.

Can someone tell me what this part is and what it is intended to be used for? It does not seem to be required for normal use of the motherboard. Thank you.

Comment: .... is it a keyfob?

Comment: I presume you've checked the end [too blurry in the photo] & it's not just a free USB stick…

Comment: I feel so dumb now. You're correct that this is in fact a usb stick. All the hoops I went through to install the drivers for the motherboard when the networking wasn't working was for nothing. If you would like to add the answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Yay me! I win the internet! ;)))

Comment: It was so small, I was certain it couldn't possibly fit into a USB slot. I guess I never thought to try until now. Go ahead and make an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: ....   If it makes you feel any better, [you're not the only one who was wondering](https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/rq7ooy/what_is_this_usb_drive_that_came_with_my_msi_z590/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**It's a USB stick.**

Free gift with every Mobo, helps you run the setup - the drivers are on it.

Its [listed on their webpage with several other potential packins](https://www.msi.com/Landing/intel-12th-gen-alder-lake-z690-h670-b660-h610-motherboard)

[image]

Comment: According to [this review](https://www.alktech.co/articles/review-msi-mpg-z790-carbon-wifi-lga1700-motherboard), also included in the box are: 2x SATA III cables; 1x 12V RGB Y-splitter cable; 1x addressable RGB extension cable; 4x EZ M.2 clips; Quick start guide; Regulatory information leaflet; Sheet of MSI decorative stickers.